# Scala: pattern matching Option with case classes and code blocks

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm starting to learn the great Scala language ang have a question about "deep" pattern matching

I have a simple `Request` class:

```
case class Request(method: String, path: String, version: String) {}
```

And a function, that tries to match an `request` instance and build a corresponding response:

```
def guessResponse(requestOrNone: Option[Request]): Response = {
    requestOrNone match {
        case Some(Request("GET", path, _)) => Response.streamFromPath(path)
        case Some(Request(_, _, _)) => new Response(405, "Method Not Allowed", requestOrNone.get)
        case None => new Response(400, "Bad Request")
    }
}
```

See, I use `requestOrNone.get` inside `case` statement to get the action `Request` object. Is it type safe, since `case` statement matched? I find it a bit of ugly. Is it a way to "unwrap" the `Request` object from `Some`, but still be able to match `Request` class fields?

What if I want a complex calculation inside a `case` with local variables, etc... Can I use `{}` blocks after `case` statements? I use IntelliJ Idea with official Scala plugin and it highlights my brackets, suggesting to remove them.

If that is possible,  is it good practice to enclose matches in matches?

```
... match {
  case Some(Request("GET", path, _)) => {
      var stream = this.getStream(path)

      stream match {
        case Some(InputStream) => Response.stream(stream.get)
        case None => new Response(404, "Not Found)
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you can name the value you match against with `@` :

```
scala> case class A(i: Int)
defined class A

scala> Option(A(1)) match {
     |   case None => A(0)
     |   case Some(a @ A(_)) => a
     | }
res0: A = A(1)
```

From the [Scala Specifications](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (*8.1.3 : Pattern Binders*) :

> A pattern binder x@p consists of a pattern variable x and a pattern p.
>   The type of the variable x is the static type T of the pattern p. This
>   pattern matches any value v matched by the pattern p, provided the
>   run-time type of v is also an instance of T , and it binds the
>   variable name to that value.

However, you do not *need* to in your example: since you're not matching against anything about the `Request` but just its presence, you could do :

```
case Some(req) => new Response(405, "Method Not Allowed", req)
```

---

For the second part, you can nest `match`es. The reason Intellij suggests removing the braces is that they are unnecessary : the keyword `case` is enough to know that the previous `case` is done.

As to whether it is a good practice, that obviously depends on the situation, but I would probably try to refactor the code into smaller blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the pattern as following (with alias).

```scala
case Some(req @ Request(_, _, _)) => new Response(405, "Method Not Allowed", req)
```

You cannot use code block in pattern, only guard (`if ...`).

There are pattern matching compiler plugin like [rich pattern matching](http://acolyte.eu.org/scalac-plugin.html).

Comment: Can you point me to a documentation page where `@` is explained? I tried to google it

Comment: Alias is part of the scala syntax (builtin, not from a plugin): `case aliasA @ PatExpr(_, subAlias @ PatExpr(_, _)) => println(s"$aliasA / $subAlias")`